# R function to substitute a character with any integer

Tags: r, bioinformatics, census

I have 2 dataframes with numeric codes that represent various jobs.
One df (`df_a`) has codes from census the other (`df_b`) has codes that represent essential jobs.
I need to create a new column in df_a with where jobs are listed as essential or non-essential based on codes in `df_b`.
The issue is that some job codes in `df_a` have character M = multiple integers in `df_b` (e.g. 123M5 in `df_a` = 12335, 12345, 12355... in `df_b`). I am trying to accomplish this by setting `M='\\d'` in df_a but not succeeding... any thoughts on a better way to approach this?
Thanks!

Comment: I thought you wanted to match on or substitute a digit value for the "M"s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you need:

```
df_a <- data.frame(job = c("1233M5", "12345", "1235M5" , "12346"))
df_b <- data.frame(essential = c(12335, 12346))

df_a$essential <- 0
df_a$essential[which(as.numeric(gsub("M", "", df_a$job)) %in% df_b$essential)] <- 1
```